# Easiest way to calculate $ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{ \log (1+x)}{x} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What is the easiest way to calculate

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{ \log (1+x)}{x}\, dx$$

?

Need a hint.

Comment: I would simply suggest integration by parts. Careful how you assign $u, du$ and $v, dv$.

Comment: @Autolatry Okay,I'll try that.

Comment: What should I take as u and v? @Autolatry

Comment: My thought would be to (possibly) try to avoid having to integrate $\log(1+x)$ but differentiating it would be ok. So choose $u=\log(1+x)$.

Comment: There is no elementary antiderivative, so an approach that looks for one will not succeed.

Comment: Ok. If i choose $ u= log(1+x)$ and $v=\frac{1}{x}$, then how would i integrate $\frac{\log x}{1+x}$ ? @Autolatry

Comment: @AndréNicolas so what do you suggest?

Comment: @Nivedita Use integration by parts again to see if a pattern emerges.

Comment: @Autolatry Would you mind posting an answer (to better explain what you just said)?

Comment: @Nivedita: Jack d'Aurizio has given an answer. It "only" works for the limits $0$ and $1$, in the sense that we will not find an elementary expression for $\int_0^w$.

Comment: Find the closed form of $I(a)=\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{(1+x)^a-1}x~dx$, and then evaluate $I'(0)$. [How hard can it be ?](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/batman/images/2/22/The_Joker_smile.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111127113628)

Answer (score 15):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n-1}}{n}\,dx=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}=\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{12}}. $$

Comment: Anything other than this one? I have done it the same way.

Comment: @Nivedita: It looks pretty straightforward to me, honestly I don't know if there are easier methods. Differentiation under the integral sign is a chance, but the computation involving the Beta function is lengthy.

Comment: in addition to this fine answer and with regards to the beta..Let $$
I_a = \int_0^1(1+x)^ax^{-1}dx
$$
your integral then is simply
$$
\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_0^1(1+x)^ax^{-1}dx = \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx
$$
now
$$
\int_0^1(1+x)^ax^{-1}dx = \int_0^1 u^a(1-u)^{-1}du = B(a+1,0)
$$
now we all know that the beta function is only defined for arguments $>0$

Answer (score 1):

We have an indefinite integral
$$
\int\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x } dx=-\operatorname{Li}_2(-x).
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_ 0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x } dx=-\operatorname{Li}_2(-1) = -\frac 1 2 \zeta(2)=- \frac{\pi^2}{12}.
$$

Of course this is overkill for this integral, but this is the method of choice if the upper limit is $1/2$ or $\phi$.