# Conversion of $\int_0^1\frac{\log( 1+x)}{x}dx$ to summation

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, summation

We know,

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^nf\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Now,we have $\int_0^1\frac{\log( 1+x)}{x}dx$
So,$f(x)=\frac{\log (1+x)}{x}$.So we find $f(r/n)$ by replacing $x$ with $r/n$. Then putting in the summation form on LHS.

Converting to summation,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)}{r}$$

Now this should evaluate to $1-\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac1{3^3}-\cdots$.How do I carry on the simplification?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Assuming $log(x)$ here is a natural log ( or it can be converted to one by appropriately scaling it). You can use the taylor series approximation of log(1+x) and further for cases where x tends to 0 ( because x = r/n and n tends to infinity) log(1+x) can be approximated to just x by ignoring the higher power terms in the taylor series.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093132/easiest-way-to-calculate-int-01-frac-log-1xx-dx , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029886/evaluate-int-01-frac-log1xx?noredirect=1 , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338307/hint-to-integrate-int-01-frac-log1xx-mathrmdx

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288830/finding-int1-0-frac-log1xxdx-without-series-expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Write \begin{align}\frac1r\log\left(1+\frac rn\right)&=\frac1r\left[\frac rn-\frac12\left(\frac rn\right)^2+\frac13\left(\frac rn\right)^3-\cdots\right]\\&=\frac1n-\frac r{2n^2}+\frac{r^2}{3n^3}-\cdots\end{align} so \begin{align}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)}{r}&=1-\frac{\sum r}{2n^2}+\frac{\sum r^2}{3n^3}-\cdots\\&=1-\frac12\int_0^1r\,dr+\frac13\int_0^1r^2\,dr-\cdots\end{align} as each term is essentially a Riemann sum.

Comment: Or treat each term $$\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)\,n^{k+1}}\,\sum_{r=1}^n\,r^k$$ as the Riemann sum for $$\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)}\,\int_0^1\,x^k\,\text{d}x\,.$$

Comment: @Batominovski Nice. I'll add this in.

Comment: Can't this be done without using $\log(1+x)$ expansion? I was trying $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\log(1+\frac rn)}{r}=\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\cdot\frac1n$ where $x=\frac rn$... Now the log part goes to $1$ (by using standard limit formula). Can the answer be derived from here?

Comment: @tatan You can't take limits whilst the term is being multiplied by another in a summation.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Okay thanks. But why can you please explain?

Comment: @tatan because otherwise you'll end up with $$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1n=1$$ which is absurd since the integral is less than $1$.

Comment: It can be seen that $$I:=\int_0^1\,\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\,\text{d}x=\int_0^\infty\,\ln\big(1+\exp(-t)\big)\,\text{d}t\,,$$
where $t:=-\ln(x)$.  Using integration by parts, we get
$$I=\int_0^\infty\,\frac{t}{\exp(t)+1}\,\text{d}t\,.$$
As $\eta(s)=\displaystyle\frac1{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty\,\frac{u^{s-1}}{\exp(u)+1}\,\text{d}u$ for all complex number $s$ with $\text{Re}(s)>0$, where $\Gamma$ is the usual gamma function and $\eta$ is the Direchlet eta function, we obtain $$I=\eta(2)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{r^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\,.$$

Comment: If you don't want to expand $\ln(1+x)$, then you can expand $$\frac{t}{\exp(t)+1}=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\,(-1)^{r-1}\,t\,\exp(-rt)$$ instead.  You can also use complex analysis to prove that $I=\eta(2)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$ without using any series expansion.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire  Oopps.  I meant to put the two comments above under the OP's question.  Wrong place.  But well, they are here already.  So I am leaving them here.  I hope you don't mind.  I didn't write these comments as a separate answer since the OP clearly wanted to use Riemann sums, but my idea doesn't use any Riemann sums.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Following the previous suggestion by TheSimpliFire

$$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)}{r}=1-\frac{\sum r}{2n^2}+\frac{\sum r^2}{3n^3}-\cdots\to1-\frac1{2\cdot 2}+\frac1{3\cdot 3}\ldots=$$$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

indeed from the well known results

- [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ (Basel problem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8337/505767)
- [Sum of Reciprocals of Squares of Odd Integers](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Reciprocals_of_Squares_of_Odd_Integers)

we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}-\frac14\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}8-\frac{\pi^2}{24}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Comment: Can't this be done without using $\log(1+x)$ expansion? I was trying $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\log(1+\frac rn)}{r}=\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\cdot\frac1n$ where $x=\frac rn$... Now the log part goes to $1$ (by using standard limit formula). Can the answer be derived from here?

Comment: @tatan No we can't since we need all the terms of the expansion and take 1 corresponds to take only one terms which leads to a wrong result.